# dotnetopenauth Samples - Step by step introduction

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am new in .Net world and planning to use dotnetopenauth api in the current project. I couldn't find step by step information to setup dotnetopenauth samples anywhere. My project has a mobile client who is going to make REST calls to backend for authentication and authorization and will be using tokens for consecutive requests. So I guess I have to concentrate on OAuthClient, OAuthResourceServer and OAuthAuthorizationServer projects which are part of samples. But I was facing issues in setting up these 3 projects in Visual studio 2010. So please let me know if there is step by step information to setup dotnetopenauth samples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about vs2010, but in vs2012 I downloaded the samples from http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/releases/v4.3/v4.3.1/DotNetOpenAuth-4.3.1.13153-samples.7z/download and opened them like any other project

Another good guide is in the book "Pro ASP.NET Web API Security: Securing ASP.NET Web API" chapters 11 and 12 give good examples of OAUTH and explain the concepts well, while chapter 13 is dedicated to implementing OAUTH using dotnetopenauth.

There are also some examples on the code project of 2-legged and 3-legged implementations

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution file w/ vs2012 and build it.

Comment: I have VS 2010 and the samples zip file doesn't contain contain solution file. After I extract the zip file it creates bunch of folders for each project. I don't see any common solution file which can pull all the projects in visual studio. Also if I try to add more than 1 project they keep failing since the dependencies are missing. I think I have to add all the dependencies thru Nuget explicitly. But again there is no information available for any of the projects part of their samples.

Comment: https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/releases/tag/v4.3.1.13153 you have full source code & solution file as per current nuget pkg.